# How to diff certain commits against master

Tags: git

I have a branch with both front-end and back-end changes.  I would like to see how just the front-end commits differ from the master branch.  is there a way to to this?

So say, that commits 124hg3 and 3t23hg are front-end commits, how can I diff it to master?

[update]
I need the collective change. So for example, if there were not back-end commits, I could just diff the branches... that's what I need to see

Comment: why not use git diff with paths i.e. `git diff master /this-folder /that/file.js` ?

Comment: I think this will work.  Thanks.

Comment: The only issue with this is if there are a lot of files that are changed.  I could just specify a directory but that will hit files that might be different that I don't care about :-/

Comment: If you need more help than a comment - put more info in your question ;).

Comment: Your use of the terms "front-end" and "back-end" with respect to either changes or commits is completely unclear in context. If your question is "how do I see the changes to a subset of files between two commits?", the answer would be `git diff <commit1> <commit2> -- <list_of_files_and_dirs>`... Perhaps providing some sample `git log` output to give an idea of what you are trying to compare might be useful...

Answer (score 2):

Sure; simply do `git diff 124hg3 master`, for example.

Comment: will this contain the changes introduced by the other commit?  I need the collective change.  So for example, if there were not back-end commits, I could just diff the branches

Comment: Not quite sure I understand; this will not show the changes introduced by the commit (for that you would do `git diff 124hg3 124hg3^`), it will show the difference between the _snapshot_ represented by `124hg3` and the snapshot represented by `master`. If you could draw a tree, maybe I'd get a better idea of what you are asking.

Comment: So if I only had front-end changes on the branch, and had multiple commits, possibly editing the same file, I could diff that branch to master and see the collective difference.  My issues is that I have front-end changes mixed with back-end ones, and I just want to diff the front-end commits.  Does that clear things up?

Comment: When you say "back end changes," do you mean changes that are on the repo server only? If so, you're golden; those changes won't be part of the diff. If instead you mean changes to just a certain part of the code, then you will need to pass the paths you want to diff (as AD7six suggests).